# '<' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'method' Django 2.0

Tags: django

Implementei uma validação com dois métodos

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #valortotal = Venda.objects.filter(id=self.id).aggregate(valortotal=Sum(F('item__produto__valor') * F('item_qtde'), output_field=FloatField()))
        #valor_nota = self.valor_nota
        #if Decimal(valortotal['valortotal']) < valor_nota():
        if self.valortotal < self.valor_nota:
         raise forms.ValidationError("O  valor do Tipo de Pagamento (dinheiro + cartão) não pode ser maior que o valor total da nota.")
        #raise forms.ValidationError(Decimal(valortotal['valortotal']))
```

e o Django retornou o seguinte erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo os métodos que retornam valores

```
def valortotal(self):
        soma = Venda.objects.filter(id=self.id).aggregate(valortotal=Sum(F('item__produto__valor') * F('item__qtde'), output_field=FloatField()))
        return soma['valortotal']

def valor_nota(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        valor_nota = self.valor_dinheiro + self.valor_cartao 
        return valor_nota
```

A Classe item

```
class Item(models.Model):
    produto = models.ForeignKey(Produto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    qtde = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
    venda = models.ForeignKey(Venda, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

A mensagem diz que na linha onde vc faz a comparação:

```
if self.valortotal < self.valor_nota:
```

Vc esta comparando duas instancias de métodos, por isso a mensagem "< não é suportado entre instancias de metodos" ('<' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'method')

Para checar isso, comente o if e dê um print no tipo dos objetos envolvidos no if, com o comando:

```
print('self.valortotal => ', type(self.valortotal))
print('self.valor => ', type(self.valor))
```

Se são realmente métodos que retornam valores, então altere seu if para:

```
if self.valortotal() < self.valor_nota():
```

Comment: ao fazer: if self.valortotal() < self.valor_nota(): ele retornou esse erro  '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'decimal.Decimal'

Comment: Eu editei o a pergunta acrescentando o método valortotal() e valor_nota

Comment: Éssa ultima msg de erro que vc relata é a mesma da sua outra pergunta, um dos dois valores da comparção é `None`, comente o if e de o comando `print( self.valortotal() is None , self.valor_nota() is None)` E vc vai ver que va ser apresentado um `True` na saida.